# Create Object if not exist using atomic() Django

Tags: django, django-models

```
    a = self.request['a']
    b = self.request['b']

    with atomic('core'):
        obj_qs = Demo.objects.filter(field_a=a, field_b=b)
        if obj_qs.count() > 0:
            raise ValidationError(detail="duplicate not allowed")

        demo = Demo(               
            field_a= a ,
            fields_b = b,
            name = name,
            desc = desc
        )
        demo.save()

    return demo
```

I try make sure that duplicate objects not created , but even if it in atomic function the validation is failed and duplicate values create

that mean i got 2 demo object that contain field_a and field_2 with same values , the value for saving and checking are the same

any ideas ??

Comment: yeah the same value , i will edit the code to be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already has this built in: [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get_or_create)

> This method is atomic assuming correct usage, correct database
>   configuration, and correct behavior of the underlying database.
>   However, if uniqueness is not enforced at the database level for the
>   kwargs used in a get_or_create call (see unique or unique_together),
>   this method is prone to a race-condition which can result in multiple
>   rows with the same parameters being inserted simultaneously.

Take a carefull note about the need for unique indexes. Use of get_or_create or your current approach, both will fail if you don't have them.

Comment: both of the fields are foreign keys , i know that you can't make unique together with those fields

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 3):

You can try this also,

```
try:
    obj = Demo.objects.get(field_a='a', field_b='b')
except Demo.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Demo(field_a=a, field_b=b, name=name,desc=desc)
    obj.save()
```

You have some other solutions too like -

- [Model.objects.get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)
- [Model.objects.update_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create)

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for a way to accomplish this the answer above is spot on but the simplified version as stated on the doc is

```
obj, created = Person.objects.update_or_create(
    first_name='John', last_name='Lennon',
    defaults={'first_name': 'Bob'},
)
```

much better much cleaner